# How can I have 2 programs and make the user choose which of the programs they want to use?

Tags: c++

I'm working on a C++ program for a project for a class. I'm new to programming and I'm wondering how can I mix 2 different programs inside 1 and make the user choose which of the 2 they want to use? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have 2 choices. You can invoke another program using the `exec`  family of functions. This will create a new process in which to invoke the existing program. You can communicate with the child process (complicated) and retrieve its exit status. The other option is if you have source code or libraries, you can compile the other code into your program and invoke it directly by calling its functions.

Comment: Also read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). New users are often put off by negative responses to their questions, but if you understand what makes a question good or bad, its easier to get the responses you are looking for.

Comment: Could try `if (x == 1) Program1(); else Program2();`.

Answer (score 1):

prog1.cpp

```
int prog1(int argc, char* argv[])
{ 
    return 0;
}
```

prog2.cpp

```
int prog2(int argc, char* argv[])
{ 
    return 0;
}
```

main switching interface:

```
int prog1(int argc, char* argv[]); //declaration
int prog2(int argc, char* argv[]); //declaration

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int  choice;
    cout << "Enter your choice ";
    cin >> choice;
    return (choice ==1?) prog1(argc,argv) : prog2(argc, argv);
}
```